# Can't press shifters (stuck)

Tags: chain, gears, shifter

My rear shifter says the chain is on gear 4, but actually it is on gear 7. When I try to swap the gear, I just can't press/pull the lever: it's stuck. The 2nd problem I have is that when I'm riding my bike and I put some pressure on the chain, it like skips every 2 seconds. I think the 2nd problem is a consequence of the first one. I don't know much about bikes, but I hope one of you can help me :), ask me anything I forgot to say.
P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: I'm sorry, but your description is too vague to allow much diagnosis.  It could be that the shifter or cable is stuck and needs to be freed, lubricated, or replaced.  Or it could be that something is just improperly adjusted.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Jasper. Since you don't know much about bikes adding a photo of the shifter and from behind and beside the rear gears will help. Meanwhile we recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site.

Answer (score 1):

How long have your cables been on the bike?

The cable may have frayed causing this problem. Also, check if your derailleur is in working condition. This might be a result of a stiff derailleur spring which causes the problem you are facing.

Get a new cable, rear mech and cable housing and your shifting will shift nicely.